# Как в Wpf изменить стандартное оформление окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

Как изменить стандартный дизайн окон?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите изменить? Как есть, и как должно стать?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/)

Как по мне - самый быстрый и легкий способ раскрасить окно

Comment: Оно должно иметь стиль по умолчанию  с темы Windows.

Comment: @IvanProdaiko тогда напишите об этом в вопросе. Мы же не телепаты :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать сторонние библиотеки как советовал [Yurii Manziuk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206432/yurii-manziuk). Я бы советовал поступить именно так, потому что кастомизация кастомизацией, но тратить время на то что уже было сделано до Вас, и в сотни раз лучше, не стоит.

Если хотите поиграться с кастомизацией окна, я кстати после Вашего вопроса тоже задался таким вопросом ради интереса, я нашел кое какой материал. Мне кажется данных ссылок будет достаточно.

- [Неплохая статья на хабре как сделать совершенно безумное кастомное
  окно](https://habrahabr.ru/post/158561/)
- [Статья показывающая в мельчайших подробностях как сделать
  windows 8 style окошко](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/)